# Install phpMyAdmin in Cloud Foundry

Tags: php, cloud-foundry

Is it possible to install phpMaAdmin in Cloud Foundry without MySQL/MariaDB Service?
I want to connect from CF phpMyAdmin to a remote MariaDB.
I use the PHP-Buildpack in CF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Follow the instructions from [this sample](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-samples/cf-ex-phpmyadmin).

Instead of running `cf create-service` for step #2, run `cf cups`. This will create a user-provided service, which allows you to manually populate the service info.

Make sure that the name of your user-provided service contains the string "mysql", this is a trigger for the [code added to the sample to configure your service](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-samples/cf-ex-phpmyadmin/blob/master/htdocs/config.inc.php#L28-L47). The full name is going to be populated as the description of the server in PHP MyAdmin.

Your user-provided service needs to have the following properties, which should reference your external server.

- hostname
- port

Ex: `cf create-user-provided-service mysql -p "hostname, port"` (the command will prompt you for the hostname and port)

Then complete the rest of the instructions as documented.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Daniel.
It works.

I tried another way too.
I dowloaded the actually Version of phpMyAdmin [here](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/)

And configured the **config.inc.php** File like this:

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'MariaDB-DEV';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'xx.xx.xx.xx';            //* IP of your MariaDB
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = 'xxx';                    //* Port of your MariaDB
```

After that i pushed it to CloudFoundry into my Space using **php_buildpack**